# get data from XML pentaho kettle

Tags: xml, pentaho, kettle

im trying to use the input step get data from XML. The problem is when i preview the rows i dont see anything, whereas in the tuotorial the person doing it get the appropriate information. I did everything right. I think the problem is because in the tutorial the XML was in the form:

```
<property1>
   <property2>
     value
   </property2>
</property1>
```

whereas in my xml the information is like this:

```
<property1 property2="value"></property1>
```

How can i fix this so kettle recognizes the value in the fields tab?

EDIT: to answer to the comment, all i did was drag the get XML Data. then right click edit step.
On the File tab i added in the "file or directory" field the XML i want to parse. Then i went to the content tab and clicked on Loop Xpath and i chose property1 there. Finally when i go to the fields tab and click Get fields i get nothing.

Comment: Please post how you've configured your `Get data from XML` step.

Comment: Updated 4 hrs ago.. please help

Answer (score 1):

If, instead of clicking 'Get Fields', I manually type in/select the following configuration on the Fields tab, I get "value" back in preview.

[image]